# Any cloud storage service could be used to read and write data like local disk?

Tags: r, cloud, storage, dropbox

I am wondering is there any cloud storage service that could be used to read and write data just like local disk.
Take R language as an example.

Read data from local disk:

```
dat01 <- read.table("E:/001.txt")
```

From cloud：

```
dat02 <- read.table("http://cloud.com/username/001.txt")
```

Write data to local disk:

```
write.table(x, file="E:/002.txt")
```

write data to cloud：

```
write.table(x, file="http://cloud.com/username/002.txt")
```

Other operations includes copy, move and delete.

I know Dropbox and the R package rDrop. I tried these and got errors saying fail to connect to the host. However, I can use Dropbox on my computer without any problem. I also read the manual of rDrop which failed to meet my command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Google Cloud Storage API for this, i-e it provides a RESTful interface for programmatically accessing Google's cloud storage technology. Here's a [Reference Guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference-guide) to consume the Cloud API.

Assuming you are familiar with [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the first time I heard about RESTful. I will look at this.

Comment: There is an R package for this now https://github.com/cloudyr/googleCloudStorageR